# combine multiple large tables using a key with each output in a new column, and duplicates concatenated into one column

Tags: linux

I am trying to compile gene annotations from multiple sources (blast, pfam, kegg, uniprot, etc; each with their own output table) into one table.  Each annotation output is a table with column1 being the gene ID and column2 being the annotation. I have ~20,000 gene IDs, and for each annotation output table only a subset of these genes are present.

I am looking for help accomplishing a few things:

1. I want the final output to be a tab separated table with column1 as gene ids, and each column thereafter to be the annotation from a different source.
   i.e. GeneID  BLASTannotation  PFAMannotation  KEGGannotation
2. I want the final output table to include ALL genes, with blank space in annotation columns for which there was no result.
3. For genes with multiple annotations from one source, I want them to be concatenated into one column under the appropriate annotation source, with no duplications.
   Input:
   c1_g1_i1  Cupin superfamily protein
   c1_g1_i1  Cupin-like domain
   c1_g1_i1  Cupin-like domain
   Output:
   c1_g1_i1  Cupin superfamily protein;Cupin-like domain

I have tried some awk array commands, but I don't understand them enough to manipulate them to do exactly what I want, and I haven't found a question that is looking for exactly what I need.  Furthermore, I have trouble figuring out how to combine more than just two tables.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Here's what I've tried:

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1,a[$1],$2}' file1 file2